# Modifying an SVGAnimateElement at runtime with Batik

Tags: java, svg, batik, svg-animate

I have an SVG document that I display in a `JSVGCanvas`. The user will be able to select a bunch of elements by dragging a a rectangle around them. I am trying to visualize this selection of elements.
I wanted to let them blink while they are selected. However adding a new `SVGAnimateElement` on each selection is much too slow. Batik will use 100% CPU time nearly forever.

Therefore I thought about preparing hose `SVGAnimateElement`s on document load and just "activate" them on selection. This is an example for this:

```
<g id="someId">
        <line ... />
        <line ... />
        <animate dur="0" from="0" to="1" repeatCount="indefinite"
                 attributeName="stroke-opacity" 
                 calcMode="discrete"/>
        <animate dur="0" from="0" to="1" repeatCount="indefinite"
                 attributeName="fill-opacity"
                 calcMode="discrete"/>
</g>
```

Since the `dur` is 0, there is no blinking visible. On selection I then set the value of `dur` to 1 to make the blink visible:

```
canvas.getUpdateManager().getUpdateRunnableQueue().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    for (SVGElement elm : currentlySelectedElements) {
      elm.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "green");
      Set<SVGAnimateElement> animateElements= getAnimateElements(elm);
      for (SVGAnimateElement anim : animateElements) {
        anim.setAttributeNS(null, "dur", "1");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The change of the stroke color is visible. The change to the SVGAnimateElement is not visible. Changing the repeatCount doesn't work, too.

Is there a reason that `SVGAnimateElement`s cannot be modified at runtime? Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you setting the ALWAYS_DYNAMIC flag? Are you creating the elements in the correct namespace? Without showing us the code it's just guesswork.

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes, ALWAYS_DYNAMIC is set. Modifying some other properties of other elements works fine. Only the change to the SVGAnimateElements isn't visible. I will add an example code snippet to the question. But if I understand you right, there is no reason why a change to an SVGAnimateElement shouldn't be visible?

Comment: It's either a bug in your code or a bug in Batik if that's what you mean. If the animation has run to completion then changing it will have no effect.

Comment: @RobertLongson `If the animation has run to completion then changing it will have no effect.` That would explain, why a change of the `repeatCount` value from 0 to `indefinite` doesn't work. However, even if I only change the value of `dur` and the initial value is `0.2` and I change it to `1`, the blinking frequency stays at 0.2.

Comment: Tell that to Batik's bugzilla bug tracker.